# PHPSpec TypeError when checking boolean value

Tags: symfony, phpspec

I have a Boolean method called supportsClass (I know but I believe in BDD/TDD all the way) that is implemented as part of this interface.

> Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface

In my spec I am test this method like this

```
$this->supportsClass(get_class($user))->ShouldReturn(false).
```

Where user is a prophet object.  When I run my specs I get this exception thrown

> [err:TypeError("Argument 1 passed to PhpSpec\Exception\ExceptionFactory::methodNotFound() must be of the type string, null given

I can't find a way to make this spec pass using any of the === or == matchers.  and the only boolean specific matchers I can find are these

```
$this->shouldBeActive(); // isActive() method should return true
$this->shouldHaveSomething(); // hasSomething() method should return true

$this->shouldNotBeActive(); // isActive() method should return false
$this->shouldNotHaveSomething(); // hasSomething() method should return false
```

As you can see the method under test doesn't match either of these.  If anyone can clarify how to test Boolean Methods that do not have is/has I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `$this->supportsClass(get_class($user))->shouldReturn(false).` (lowercase should in shouldReturn method name)